# icons for WPF application

Tags: wpf, silverlight, icons, vector-graphics

It's recommended to use vector images in WPF application because of its scalability. Where I can find a free icons in vector format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can get some them from here

http://vector.tutsplus.com/articles/web-roundups/60-free-vector-icon-packs-for-design-professionals/

Answer (score 3):

Syncfusion Metro Studio 2 is out (1700 icons). Currently provided free.
You can get it [here.](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/metrostudio)

Answer (score 1):

Check [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/). From time to time they publish lists of free high quality  icon libraries and other graphic resources.

Here are some of them:

[50 New Free High-Quality Icon Sets (with Easter Icons!)](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/01/50-new-free-high-quality-icon-sets/)
[50 Fresh Useful Icon Sets For Your Next Design](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/07/50-fresh-useful-icon-sets-for-your-next-design/)
[50 Free High-Quality Icon Sets](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/02/16/50-beautiful-useful-and-free-icon-sets/)
[40 Professional Icon Sets For Free Download](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/05/21/40-professional-icon-sets-for-free-download/)
[35 (Really) Incredible Free Icon Sets](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/03/06/35-really-incredible-free-icon-sets/)
[20+ Free And Fresh Icon Sets](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/08/25/20-free-and-fresh-icon-sets/)

Comment: amazing icons, but it's a png

Answer (score 1):

Look here for icons in Adobe Illustrator (AI) and PNG formats under Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 United States License (CC BY 3.0). 
http://www.pixelledesigns.com/free-mobile-app-icons.htm

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

http://www.tehkseven.net/news/478-free-svg-vector-icons-the-seven-icon-pack

http://www.openclipart.org/

Answer (score 0):

you can use vector icons from https://www.webiconio.com. This icons are free, you can view FAQ section.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a large collection of icons in vector format, this is my go to icon packs.

https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro.IconPacks